# How to evaluate an expression and use the result in newcommand?

Tags: macros, calc

I am trying to declare a newcommand

```
\newcommand{\seq}[3]{#1_#2, #1_{#2 + 1} \cdots ,#1_#3}
```

What I want is basically to print the sequence `$v_0, v_1, \cdots, v_N$` by calling  `\seq{v}{0}{N}` but it is printing `$v_0, v_{0+1}, \cdots, v_N$`. Basically, I want to evaluate and use the result of expression `#2 + 1`.

How will I do that?

Comment: `\newcommand{\seq}[3]{#1_#2, #1_{\the\numexpr#2 + 1\relax}, \cdots ,#1_#3}` works if `#2` is a number. It should probably be made more robust by checking if `#2` is an integer first and print `#2+1` otherwise.

Comment: #2 is always a number, so it works.

Comment: Do you want it for integers only or also for other kinds of numbers, e.g. real numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your objective is straightforward to achieve if you can use LuaLaTeX.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}  
\newcommand{\seq}[3]{#1_{#2}, #1_{\directlua{tex.sprint(#2+1)}}, \dots ,#1_{#3}}
\begin{document}
$\seq{v}{0}{N}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that I recommend using `\dots` (or `\ldots`), not `\cdots`.

Comment: what's the difference between `\dots` and `\cdots`?

Comment: @chelsea - `\cdots` raises the dots above the baseline. For the problem at hand, `\dots` seems more appropriate from a typographic point of view.

Answer (score 6):

This checks whether `#2` is an (unsigned) integer and in this case does the operation; otherwise it just appends `+1`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\seq}{mmm}
 {
  \chelsea_seq:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \chelsea_seq:nnn
 {
  #1\sb{#2}, % first item
  \regex_match:nnTF { \A [0-9]+ \Z } { #2 }
   {% #2 is a number
    #1\sb{ \int_eval:n { #2 + 1 } }
   }
   {% #2 is not a number
    #1\sb{ #2+1 }
   }
  ,\dots,#1\sb{#3}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\seq{v}{0}{N}$

$\seq{v}{1}{N}$

$\seq{w}{n}{N}$

\end{document}
```

[image]